# Search in Listview related to database and using Retrofit

Tags: android

In my Listview i have a list of Users, I want to search an object from this list according to Noun_Pronoun attribute. but I always have a wrong object as result, and when I delete the search string I have an empty result !
............................................................................

```js
public class InvitationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView ClassInvitLv;
    SearchView ClassInvitSv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitation);


        ClassInvitLv=findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ClassInvitSv=findViewById(R.id.sv);
        getUsers();

    }


    private void getUsers(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.BaseUrl))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        MyInterface myInterface=retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);

        Call<List<User>> call = myInterface.getUsers();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

                final List<User> UserList = response.body();

                final UsersAdapter usersAdapter=new UsersAdapter(InvitationActivity.this, R.layout.custom_row, UserList );
                ClassInvitLv.setAdapter(usersAdapter);



                ClassInvitSv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                        for (int c=0; c<UserList.size(); c++) {

                            
 if(!(UserList.get(c).getNoun_Pronoun()).contains(s))

                                UserList.remove(UserList.get(c));

                        }

                        usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                      return false;
                    }
                });

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you want to load all users from server using retrofit API later on you want to perform search operation locally ? is this the your requirement ?

Comment: UserList should not be final. You remove item from final list

Comment: Change this line `UserList.remove(UserList.get(c));` to `UserList.remove(c);` and try

Comment: In the launch of activity, I load all users from server, but for the search operation I want that it be locally, from the UserList

Comment: Better to create a copy of master userlist and pass to the adapter, by doing this you will not loose the master user list. Problem with your code is you gonna loose master user list as user can perform search as many time he want. But you are deleting the items on each search from master userlist. At some moment your master user list will get empty .

Comment: UserList.remove(c) give the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have modified your code, it should fix your issue. Expecting that in `UsersAdapter` class you are not making any copy of the list we passing in constructor. if you are doing that then create a method in `UsersAdapter` class say `updateUserList(List<User> filterList)` and handle accordingly.

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

            final List<User> UserList = response.body();
            final List<User> filterList = new ArrayList<User>();
            filterList.addAll(UserList);

            final UsersAdapter usersAdapter=new UsersAdapter(InvitationActivity.this, R.layout.custom_row, filterList );
            ClassInvitLv.setAdapter(usersAdapter);



            ClassInvitSv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    filterList.clear();
                    for (int c=0; c<UserList.size(); c++) {


                       if((UserList.get(c).getNoun_Pronoun()).contains(s))

                            filterList.add(UserList.get(c));

                    }

                    usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                  return false;
                }
            });

        }
```

Better to create a method in `UserAdapter` class like below and call from method `onQueryTextChange` as `usersAdapter.updateUserList(filterList)`;  where calling `usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`;

```
public void updateUserList(List<User> filterList) {
  // clear adapter list
  // add all filterList to your adapter list
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```